# JSON type object only has parse and stringify methods, but I want to access the objects data

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, typeorm

I have a project with NestJS, Typescript and Typeorm. I'm working with the following class Entity

```js
class Event {
user: string,
createdAt: Date,
type: string,
data: JSON
}
```

In one of my methods I'm making a query to get some events, but I want to access just a few properties of the `data` attribute because the object has a lot information I don't really need. The problem is that when I try to access the json, for example: `receivedEvent.data.myProperty` typescript tells me that this property is not available in type JSON. The only solution I can think of is changing the type of the `data` attribute to a string and parse it to json after the query, but I want to know if there is any other solution to this. This is the code I'm using to query the events:

```js
async getLogs(loanId: string): Promise<Event[]> {
    const events = await this.eventRepository.find({
      select: ['createdAt', 'user', 'type', 'data'],
      where: {
        type: In([
          'early_payoff',
        ]),
        data: Raw(
          /* istanbul ignore next */
          () => 'data->"$.GUID" = :id',
          { id: loanId },
        ),
      },
      order: {
        id: 'DESC',
      },
    });

    console.log(events);

    
    return events.map(e=>{
      /// This is where my problem is
      const json: any = {"withdrawReason": e.data.withdrawReason}
      return {...e, data: json}
    });
  }
```

Comment: `JSON` is just an interface with methods for parsing/un-parsing JSON data. If your class needs to hold the actual data it's better to type it accordingly to the shape of data you expect to receive.

Comment: Since the ```data``` attribute is used as an historical reference (sort of like a log of any event) it's not necessarily the same shape every time, it could have a thousand different shapes. It is built this way because of the project's arquitecture which is event-sorurcing. But your comment helped me understand the root of this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick to solution to this problem. I set the event.data to another variable with type  and after that Typescript doesn't throws error.

```js
return events.map(e=>{
      /// This is where my problem was
      const json: any = e.data
      const jsonData: any = {"withdrawReason": json.withdrawReason}
      return {...e, data: jsonData}
    });
```